# How can you output the values in the same page?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to build an email scraper on Django and that when you enter a URL, the result should be outputted in the same page. For now, the result is outputted in another page but I want it to be in the same one. I don't know how should I do this.

I know I should be using an AJAX request but don't know how to make the form take the action of the AJAX request.

Any help I would really appreciate it!

**form:**

```
<form class="card card-sm" action="{% url 'emailsearcher' %}" id='InputSearch' method="GET">
    <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" placeholder="Introduce URL" name="Email" id="InputSearch" value="{{ Email.get }}" aria-describedby="searchHelp">
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
        <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="search" onclick="total()">Find Email Address</button>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: for ajax form does not take an action, you would have to write javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Answer (score 1):

instead of submitting the form use Javascript and [The XMLHttpRequest Object](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) to send data to your API and receive and view the results. you can learn more about AJAX [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp). there are some examples too.

For the backend of your requests, you have to implement some APIs which likely you want to use django-rest-framework. you are lucky because I have an awesome document to [learn the Django REST Framework in Minutes](https://medium.com/better-programming/learn-django-rest-framework-in-minutes-ef5159dc60ab).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use html form's submit event, instead create an async function that uses Javascript's fetch method. You can check the Mozilla's Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The following snippet is an example of how post a json payload with your input to your python api:

```
<script>
function submitURL() {
  const url = document.querySelector("#InputSearch").value;
  const data = { url };

  fetch('https://my-api.com', {
    method: 'POST'
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
}
</script>
```

And call the function at the submit button, as an "onclick" event, like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="search" onclick="submitURL">
  Find Email Address
</button>
```

Comment: Do I need to create an API for the python script or what is the URL it should fetch?